# How to simulate a fake MouseOver on a Flash applet in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, greasemonkey, mouseover

I listen to internet radio at http://player.play.it/player/player.htm and it works pretty well, except for one minor issue.  The Flash applet that runs the radio player has a timer on it, where if you don't move the mouse over the player every once in a while, it decides you're idle and shuts off the stream, even if you're not actually idle, but just working on something else with the radio player running in the background.

Is there any way I can send a fake MouseOver message to this applet to keep it from cutting me off in the middle of a song, maybe with a GreaseMonkey script?  I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the HTML that is served up with the player....

```
<body bgcolor="#000000" onmouseout="windowActive();" onmouseover="windowActive();">
```

..It looks like `windowActive()` is being called a lot in different places on the page. You could try just calling it yourself, on a timer and see what happens.